# Ambiguous Overload Templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following templated code

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T1>
void foo(std::vector<T1> bar) {
    std::cout << "GENERIC" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T1>
void foo(std::vector<std::vector<T1>> bar) {
    std::cout << "SPECIFIC (vector)" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T1, int SIZE>
void foo(std::vector<std::array<T1, SIZE>> bar) {
    std::cout << "SPECIFIC (array)" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(2, std::vector<int> { 1, 2, 3});
    std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> b(2, std::array<int, 3> {4, 5, 6});

    foo(a);
    foo(b);
}
```

which produces

```
SPECIFIC (vector)
GENERIC
```

I'm wondering why the vector-of-vector version is called with the specific template, but the vector-of-array version is called with the generic?

Comment: FYI: You can simplify this, with the same issue, by removing the outer `vector` on all of them. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/YYP29O)

Comment: @ChrisMM good catch. This example was synthesized from my production code, where the nested structure is necessary.

Comment: MSVC calls vector-of-arrays version: https://godbolt.org/z/7Gfeb0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template<typename T1, size_t SIZE>
void foo(std::vector<std::array<T1, SIZE>> bar) {
    std::cout << "SPECIFIC (array)" << std::endl;
}
```

You should use `std::size_t` instead of `int`.
[run here](http://cpp.sh/7ntaf)

**Edit :**
Actually, your comments and my intuition about the code led me to dig into the topic. At first glance, a standard developer ( like me ) expect compiler to convert `int` to `std::size_t`(because they are both integral type and implicitly converting is very trivial) and select `void foo(std::vector<std::array<T1, SIZE>> bar)` as best specialization. So while reading [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) page i found this :

> If a non-type template parameter is used in the parameter list, and
>   the corresponding template argument is deduced, the type of the
>   deduced template argument ( as specified in its enclosing template
>   parameter list, meaning references are preserved) must match the type
>   of the non-type template parameter exactly, except that cv-qualifiers
>   are dropped, and except where the template argument is deduced from an
>   array bound—in that case any integral type is allowed, even bool
>   though it would always become true:

As always, of course, you must read few more times than once to understand what it means :)

So an interesting result comes out.

**Already our desired specialization is not selected but if the compiler had been forced to select, it would be an error.**

```
template<typename T1, int SIZE>
void foo(std::vector<std::array<T1, SIZE>> bar) {
    std::cout << "SPECIFIC (array)" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> b(2, std::array<int, 3> {4, 5, 6});

    foo(b); // P = std::vector<std::array<int,(int)SIZE>
            // A = std::vector<std::array<int,(unsigned_long)SIZE>>
            // error: deduced non-type template argument does not have the same
            // type as its corresponding template argument */
}
```

[run code](http://cpp.sh/3szv3)

Another interesting thing is :

**If the non-type template argument had not been deduced, there would be no restriction which forces argument and template types to be same.**

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T1, int SIZE>
void foo(std::vector<std::array<T1, SIZE>> bar) {
    std::cout << "SPECIFIC (array)" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> b(2, std::array<int, 3> {4, 5, 6});

    foo<int,3>(b);
}
```

[run code](http://cpp.sh/43ivr)

Comment: @Xaser because second template argument of array is of type `size_t`...

Comment: Considering R2RT's comment, there appear to be compiler specific differences.

Answer (score 7):

I *think* this is simply due to one line from `[temp.deduct.call]/4`

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced A identical to A

To clarify, `A` means the parameter, from `[temp.deduct.call]/1`

> ...template argument deduction with the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it A)...

As has already been pointed out, changing `template<typename T1, int SIZE>` to `template<typename T1, size_t SIZE>` fixes the issue you are seeing. As stated in `[temp.deduct.call]/4`, the compiler is looking to deduce an `A` that is identical to `A`. Since an `std::array` has template arguments `<class T, size_t N>` (from `[array.syn]`), it's second parameter is in fact `size_t`, not `int`.

Therefore, for the template deduction, your generic function of `template<typename T1>` is able to match **exactly** the type of `A`, where-as your specialized `template<typename T1, int SIZE>` is not an **exact** match. I believe MSVC is incorrect in its deduction.